# Regex to fetch particular string from an output

Tags: regex

While executing a below command in linux

```
root@11.222.33.38.11:~#  cat /etct/user.conf
```

I will get following data.

```
[General]
ui_language=US_en
```

From this i need to fetch the value of ui_language (US_en) only using regular expression.

Comment: you can do this using pattern and matcher class.

Comment: @divz Which programming language are you using to code?

Comment: java lag is using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe to grep and sed:

```
cat foo.txt | grep 'ui_language=' | sed 's/ui_language=\(.*\)/\1/g'
```

Replace foo.txt with your file name.

Example:

```
host$ cat foo.txt 
[General]
ui_language=US_en
host$ cat foo.txt | grep 'ui_language=' | sed 's/ui_language=\(.*\)/\1/g'
US_en
host$
```

EDIT: I didn't realize you wanted to use java. This was not originally tagged with java. 
You can do that with the following:

MatchExample.java

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class MatchExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes((new File(args[0])).toPath());
        String s = new String(bytes,"UTF-8");

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("ui_language=(.*)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        if (matcher.find()){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }

}
```

This takes filename as the first parameter.

Compile:

```
host$ javac MatchExample.java
```

Run:

```
host$ java MatchExample foo.txt 
US_en
host$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("US_en");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
    if (matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

here,mydata is a string from which you want to fetch data

Comment: one thing is the value of ui_language= may varies..some times its value will be US_es or so one...

Comment: store that string in one variable then pass that variable in pattern class compile method.

Comment: But we cant predict what langs are coming